# Rmagick blocking Rails from loading with, library not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick

I had to reinstall OS X Mavericks and after restoring my computer from Time Capsule backup, I can no longer boot up Rails. I'm getting the following error:

```
$ rails s
/Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
  from /Users/Bob/Sites/mysite/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  from /Users/Bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mysite/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've reinstalled Imagemagick, and done bundle update/installs and it has had no effect. How can I get Rails running?